# ASP.NET MVC load data from Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I tried to follow the instruction the link here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/

But if I am going the run my program I'm having this error:

```
AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in Index.cshtml
+
@foreach (var item in Model) {
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

I'm not sure if this error is related to my database connection because if I will comment out the for loop it will execute correctly but there is no data load from my table, or is there missing configuration on my model or controller not really sure coz Im very new to this platform.

Here is my current index.html

```
@model IEnumerable<NetCoreWebApp.Models.Album>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
                </th>                 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any Suggestion/comments will appreciate, TIA

Comment: Do you have the error message?

Comment: Can you show the controller code and how you pass `IEnumerable<NetCoreWebApp.Models.Album>` to view? I found that your issue is related to `foreach` loop which tried to iterate null collection.

Comment: my controller code is the same on the reference link that I'm following

Comment: I tried example in referenced link and just working fine. Perhaps you should include exception message, inner exception and stack trace to get more insights.